# Applet's, HTML and Java

Tags: java, html, eclipse, jsp, applet

I'm trying to create a website to run my project and for that I need to create an applet which will enable the user to "play around" with what i'm creating.
To give you a detailed overview of my project, here's my layout so far as it was coded in the `index.jsp` file.

Browser

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+       File upload option           +                  +
+  ---------------------------       +  ------------    +
+  |                         |       +  |          |    +
+  |                         |       +  |          |    +
+  |                         |       +  | Applet   |    +
+  |          Applet         |       +  | Options  |    +
+  |                         |       +  | (toggles,|    +
+  |                         |       +  |  etc)    |    +
+  |                         |       +  |          |    +
+  ---------------------------       +  ------------    +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

So what, i want to do is basically have an empty(=white) Applet initially which will wait to load the file from the user. And then refresh based on users preferences from the option pane.

Here's my projects layout.

```
<Project name>
    <Java Resources>
        <src>
            <Implementation>
                object1.java
                object2.java
                ...
            <Website stuff>
                AppletWindow.java
                UploadFile.java
     <Uploads> //When this project is uploaded on a server, here is where i want all the uploads to go.
     <WebContent>
         <css>
         <META-INF>
         <WEB-INF>
         index.jsp
         AppletWindow.class //Which i manually compiled from the folder outside Eclipse, but i need this to refresh everytime I run the server.
```

What I'm struggling with right now is:

1. Uploading a file in to my Uploads folder so I can access it from the `.java` files in my `Implementation` package
2. Making the applet run. My applet shows the initial white page that i want but only when I right-click on it run it as an applet in Eclipse IDE. In the `index.jsp` it only shows the background color of the webpage and allocates space for the applet.

Can you give me some tips on where to start?

Here's the html code I use to call the applet class

```
<object codetype="application/java" classid="java:ApplicationWindow.class" width="450" height="350"></object>
```

All that stuff is uploaded on a `Apache Tomcat 8 server` which was set up locally via Eclipse.

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Comment: no, it's for my thesis. I'm looking for what is easier, but most of all faster.

Comment: Applets add a level of complexity and browser resistance/blocking that does not happen with an app launched free floating using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) - but to debug either an embedded applet ***or*** a free floating JWS app., a tip: Be sure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show.  If there is no output at the default level, raise the level and try it again.